# Get and Set function c++

Tags: c++, function, class, visual-c++, methods

i just wanted to know if someone could help me about my code,i am a little confused to why it is not working like i want it to maybe i am misunderstanding something...The point of the program is to write a class with two functions to set and get a number but later on the main part of the code i have wanted it to print out a 2.52 number not just the number 2.Thank you if anyone helps :) .

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Class
{
public:
    void Set(float x)
    {
        number = x;
    }
    int Get()
    {
        return number;
    }
private:
    float number;
};
int main()
{
    Class object;
    object.Set(2.52);
    cout << "The number is: " << object.Get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to change `int Get()` to `float Get()` ;)?

Comment: Get return an int. When  `object.Get()` is executed, the value of `number` which is the one you set, 2,53, is converted to an `int` : 2. This what is outputed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you return an `int` from `Get()` so `number` will be converted in an `int`.

You should also make `Get()` `const` since it's will not change anything in the `Class` object when you call the function. Making it `const` makes it possible to pass instances of `Class` to functions taking a `Class` by `const&`:

```
#include <iostream>

class Class
{
public:
    void Set(float x)
    {
        number = x;
    }
    float Get() const // returning float and added const
    {
        return number;
    }
private:
    float number;
};

void tester(const Class& obj) // a function taking a Class by const reference:
{
    std::cout << "The number is: " << obj.Get() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Class object;
    object.Set(2.52);
    tester(object);
}
```

Without the added `const` compilation would fail.

Answer (score 0):

you can change get method type(float) like that

```
class Class
{
public:
    void Set(float x)
    {
        number = x;
    }
    float Get()
    {
        return number;
    }
private:
    float number;
};
int main()
{
    Class object;
    object.Set(2.52);
    cout << "The number is: " << object.Get();

    return 0;
}
```